# TFS gated check-in sudden reject

Tags: tfs

My gated check-in build definition was working fine for a month, but suddenly it stopped committing anything without any reason.

[image: Build log]

I found [the same question at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/tfsbuild/thread/2f2c29fc-ec7c-4dca-9ed6-6a8e46656d26), but in my case there are no errors at all.

Comment: Are there any details in 'View Log' section? Have you try to reboot TFS service at your TFS server? Sometime it locks files, and all following builds failed due to lack of permissions to overwrite file.

Comment: Go into "View Log" and check there. Your build failed after the compilation & the unit test execution, but it sure failed.

Comment: @pantelif I found a couple of warnings in detailed log (they were not marked with yellow exclamations)

Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'c:\builds\8\iip gated check-in\sources\sources\ztest\bin\release\ztest.dll' was not found.
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'CommandLine' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'c:\builds\8\iip gated check-in\sources\sources\ztest\bin\release\ztest.dll' was not found.

Comment: in this case, @dmitry-fedorkov, you could copy content from 'View Log' from one of previous 'green' successful builds, and from failed one, and compare them using diff tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was a problem: a `[ClassCleanup]` method was throwing an exception. So all test are passed, but the whole build is failed. Thus the build is marked 'partially succeed' (gated check-in rejected), but in build log you can't find any error or warning marks.